# If And statement with a foreach for AD Users in Powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement

```
$names = Import-CSV C:\PowerShell\TerminatedEmployees.csv
$Date = Get-Date
foreach ($name in $names) 
{
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity "$($name.TextBox37)" | select Name | Out-File "C:\Powershell\ADUserMemberships\$($name.TextBox37)Memberships.txt"
    $ADgroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity "$($name.TextBox37)" | where {$_.Name -ne "Domain Users"}
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity "$($name.TextBox37)" -MemberOf $ADgroups -Confirm:$false
    Disable-ADAccount -Identity "$($name.TextBox37)"
    Get-ADUser -Identity "$($name.TextBox37)" | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=DisabledAccounts,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXXX,DC=XXX"
    Set-ADUser -Identity "$($name.TextBox37)" -Description "Disabled $Date"
}
```

This is an already working script I have.  However, I realized I need to check 2 properties on the AD user to determine if they need to need to go through my foreach statement.  Both properties need to be met.  If they are then there's no reason for the AD users to be processed.

1. The AD user is already disabled.
2. The AD user already resides in the Disabled OU.

I'm thinking this needs to be done in an If -And statement.  But does this need to be done before the foreach or inside the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

Start out by retrieving the user account with `Get-ADUser` and then inspect the `Disabled` property + compare the Disabled OU to the `DistinguishedName` of the user:

```
$names = Import-CSV C:\PowerShell\TerminatedEmployees.csv
$Date = Get-Date
$DisabledOU = "OU=DisabledAccounts,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXXX,DC=XXX"
foreach ($name in $names) 
{
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity "$($name.TextBox37)"
    if(-not($ADUser.Enabled) -and $ADUser.DistinguishedName -like "*,$DisabledOU")
    {
        # no need to proceed, skip to next name in foreach loop
        continue
    }
    $ADGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity "$($name.TextBox37)" 
    $ADGroups |Select-Object Name |Out-File "C:\Powershell\ADUserMemberships\$($name.TextBox37)Memberships.txt"
    # no need to call Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership again
    $ADgroups = $ADGroups | where {$_.Name -ne "Domain Users"}
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity "$($name.TextBox37)" -MemberOf $ADgroups -Confirm:$false
    Disable-ADAccount -Identity "$($name.TextBox37)"
    $ADUser | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $DisabledOU
    Set-ADUser -Identity "$($name.TextBox37)" -Description "Disabled $Date"
}
```